# Connecting Azure Data Warehouse to Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-lake, polybase, sql-data-warehouse

From Azure Data Warehouse can we connect to Azure Catalog tables or Lake Store files as external tables?

I want to be able to run SQL queries against the Azure Data Warehouse, but want to get the data from the Data Lake instead.

Comment: What do you mean by Azure Catalog?  If you mean Azure Data Catalog, then this is not currently exposed in Azure Data Lake.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can connect to files in Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) as external tables using Polybase.  This was announced in Feb 2017 [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/sql-data-warehouse-now-supports-seamless-integration-with-azure-data-lake-store/).

As per the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/sql-data-warehouse-now-supports-seamless-integration-with-azure-data-lake-store/), complete the following steps:

1. Create a scoped database credential
2. Create an external datasource, pointing at your datalake using the credential created above
3. Create an external file format (eg comma, pipe-delimited etc) for your table
4. Create an external table, using the external datasource, eg

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.yourTable (
       col1    INT NOT NULL,
       col2    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       col3    DATETIME NOT NULL
   )
   WITH (
       LOCATION = '/someADLSFolder/',
       DATA_SOURCE = yourDataSource,
       FILE_FORMAT = yourFileformat,
       REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,
       REJECT_VALUE = 0
       );
   ```